# Oldest discovered maths notes

Tags: math-history

What are the oldest discovered mathematics notes ? Which country was it discovered in and by who was it discovered ? What topic/topics did it cover mostly and how has this contributed to modern day mathematics.

Comment: Do you meansomething like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Mathematical_Papyrus

Comment: Depending on what you consider to be "notes", how about what is presented at [What's the Oldest Mathematical Artifact](https://numberwarrior.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/whats-the-oldest-mathematical-artifact-i/)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [history of science and mathematics stackexchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Migrate rather than close?

Comment: See references to some ancient sources into [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7745/how-did-the-integer-degrees-angles-counting-being-first-adopted-in-geometry-and).

Answer (score 3):

There's a Babylonian clay tablet from about 1700 BCE with a square drawn on it—a side of the square is labelled with the Cuneiform for $60$, and the diagonal is labelled with an accurate value of $60 \sqrt2$. (Or alternatively, $1$ and $\sqrt2$ expressed in sixtieths. The numbers are written in base $60$.)

There's also a list of Pythagorean triples, from the same period.

I think both tablets were discovered in what is now Iraq.

I'm sure someone else will come up with something older, though.

Comment: Thank you :) do you have a source for where you got this information from ? So I can further investigate. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan I read about it in *Episodes from the Early History of Mathematics* by Asger Aaboe, but it's pretty famous and well have its own Wikipedia article (probably possible to track down by starting from something like "Babylonian Mathematics").

Comment: @Dan Since the question has been closed, I'll flag it and ask for it to be migrated to History of Science and Mathematics in the hope that they'll think it's on topic and reopen it.

Comment: okay thanks :) thats would be great.

Comment: @Dan Moderator's suggestion is to ask again in History of Science and Mathematics, but to make it more focused than this one.